# react-leaflet _ "Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)" with valid coordinates on Polyline

Tags: leaflet, nan, react-leaflet, polyline

**Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)** appears with `react-leaflet`, and comes from `leaflet` itself, as it seems to come from the core library, even if coordinates are actually valid.

Code:

```js
const plottedPoints: LatLong[] = [
                    [29.69937, -95.32803],
                    [30, 30],
                    [29.69937, -95.32803]
                     ]

const polylineTraveledOptions: PathOptions = {lineCap: 'square', lineJoin: 'miter', color: blue50, weight: 4}

    return(
    <div id="map" style={{height: '400px', width: '555px'}}>
        <MapContainer
            // Won't let the user zoom out too much and see outside the world's layout
            zoomSnap={0.5}
            zoomDelta={0.5}
            // We have a custom positioned zoom control
            zoomControl={false}
            scrollWheelZoom={false}
            // Fixes the map's drag to its bounds
            maxBoundsViscosity={1}
            style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="https://stadiamaps.com/">Stadia Maps</a>, &copy; <a href="https://openmaptiles.org/">OpenMapTiles</a> &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png"
            />
            <ZoomControl position="bottomright" />
            <Polyline pathOptions={polylineTraveledOptions} positions={plottedPoints} />
        </MapContainer>
    </div>
)
```

I'm also setting the **mapBounds**:

```js
    const map = useMap()

    // Zooms in the correct size for the polyline we've set
    const mapBounds = [[29.69937, -95.32803], [29.69937, -95.32803]]
    map.fitBounds(mapBounds, {padding: [30, 30]})
    // Won't let the user zoom to a world's map that's duplicated
    map.setMinZoom(2)
    // Won't let the user drag outside of the world's map
    map.setMaxBounds([
        [-90, -300],
        [90, 300],
    ])
```

May it because it doesn't support **overlapping** of vectors on Polylines, as two of the coords are on the **same location**?
Or is it because the `mapBounds()` function would be on the **same point**, instead of something that can be calculated as a square?
Or else...?

There's also not much out there on **how to fix it**, a part of this link: https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim/issues/29 which is about the snake animation - and I don't think it's related.

Please, enlighten me.